# What is the exact scope of the Mage Slayer caster level penalty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The *Mage Slayer*, *Pierce Magical Concealment* and *Pierce Magical Protection*  feats (Complete Arcane, p. 81 & 82) have interesting benefits, but they also have a penalty:

> **Special**: Taking this feat reduces your caster level for all your spells and spell-like abilities by 4.

I am wondering what is the exact scope of this penalty; most notably, does it affect the caster level of spells the character could cast through wands, scrolls or other magical items?

*Note: I suspect this penalty is solely there to keep casting classes out of this feat line, however who knows...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it shouldn't affect items.**

*Staves* and *scrolls* are the two major item categories that reference caster level.

However,

> **Special:** Taking this feat reduces your caster level for all **your** *spells* and *spell-like abilities* by 4.

While the staves and scrolls do contain spells, they are not your spells - they are spells 'being cast from the scroll' or 'cast from the staff', wording that endures throughout all uses throughout all the rulebooks.  'Your spell' or 'spell-like-ability' is conversely only used to describe spells inherent to the character - granted by level, feat, or rarely, by a different spell or ability.

There's no specific text clarifying this, but it's fairly safe to say that when casting a spell from a stave or a scroll, you do not suffer the -4 penalty to CL.